# Dual selection sorting an array - honestly stumped

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort, selection-sort

```
void dualSort(int [], double [], int);
int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;            // Array size
    double accountNumbers[ARRAY_SIZE];      // Array with 1000 elements
    double accountBalances[ARRAY_SIZE];     // Loop counter variable
    int count = 0;                              // Input file stream object
    ifstream inputFile;

    // Open the file.
    inputFile.open("FinalNumbers.txt");

    // Read the numbers from the file into the array
    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> accountNumbers[count] >> accountBalances[count] ) {
        count++;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    // Display the read data
    cout << "The bank account numbers are: " << endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++) {
        cout << accountNumbers[count] << "\n" << accountBalances[count] << " " << endl;
    }

    void dualSort(int accountNumbers[], double accountBalances, int ARRAY_SIZE);



}
```

I am required to use the selection sort or bubble sort algorithm.

I have **Bank Account Numbers** that have to be correspondingly and ascending sorted with there **Account Balance**, all the data is read from a file.

After sorting the data I have to rewrite it into another file, which is the least of my worries.

So the question is how do I go about sorting my `accountNumbers` in ascending order along with their `accountBalance` following them.

Comment: The better way to do this is to sort just an array of indices instead of sorting two arrays.  What if there were 3, 4, 5, or 10 arrays that needed to have the same order?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie True, but given that the OP has just 2 arrays it is just a trade-off between efficiency and ease of access.

Comment: Question: are you explicitly required to sort the array, or do you only have to write them out in sorted order? It's not the same thing, and if the latter is the case then there is a very elegant and efficient solution.

Comment: @NirFriedman "Next you should sort the values from the input file in ascending order by account number keeping the corresponding balance paired with the account number. You may use a selection sort or bubble sort algorithm. You cannot use the sorting algorithms within the standard template library."

Comment: @chris213 And that main is already given to you I guess?

Comment: @NirFriedman Next I will be moving the sorted contents to a new file, afterwards I will be prompting the user to enter an "account number" and printing out the "account balance" corresponding to the account number.

Comment: @NirFriedman no, I created the main. Yes I am still learning, first program involving data from files and I'm no means an expert with arrays and functions yet.

Comment: @chris213 That's fine, I thought the main was given. You don't need to use two arrays then, you can use an array of structs, it will simplify everything  tremendously, also you can use a vector.

Comment: @NirFriedman must use arrays or vectors and honestly not familiar with structures yet, if you provided an example that would be great though for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort according to `accountNumbers` but apply every swap operation to both arrays.

Here is the code using selection sort:

```
void dualSort(int accountNumbers[], double accountBalances[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
 int minIndex;

 for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; i++)
 {
  minIndex = i;

  for(int j = i + 1; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
  {
   if(accountNumbers[j] < accountNumbers[minIndex])
   {
    minIndex = j;
   }
  }

  swap(accountNumbers[i], accountNumbers[minIndex]);
  swap(accountBalances[i], accountBalances[minIndex]);
 }
}
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me thank you. But, when I toss it into my code I get three errors by each of the first brackets in each function, "Function definition is not allowed here".

Comment: @chris213 Where do you paste it? You have to paste it above the `main()` function. Replace `void dualSort(int [], double [], int);` in your code with this.

Comment: Silly mistake on my end, also had to add prototypes because function call was ambiguous. Again thank you helped a lot.

Comment: *but apply every swap operation to both arrays* -- Not if you use an array of indices and swap those instead of swapping both arrays.

Comment: You do not need to define all these swap functions. You can use `std::swap(a, b)` for both ints and doubles

Comment: @GillBates Thanks, I just did that to make the steps clear to the OP.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar Yes but, when I figure out how to send the data into a new file I'll know for sure if it did / worked right.

Comment: @chris213 OK please consider accepting the answer if it does work right, otherwise ask for clarification and we will work towards the solution.

Comment: @GillBates Removed the `swap` functions as suggested by you, tested that it works without them too. Thanks for the incite.

Answer (score 1):

to do bubble sort algorithm you must do 2 `for` loops and a temporary variable

```
int tempAccNumber=0;
int tempAccBalance=0;
for(int j=0;j<ARRAY_SIZE-1;++j)
    for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE-1;++i)
          if(accountNumbers[i]>accountNumbers[i+1])
          {             
              tempAccNumber=accountNumbers[i];
              accountNumbers[i]=accountNumbers[i+1];
              accountNumbers[i+1]=tempAccNumber;
              tempAccBalance=accountBalances[i];
              accountBalances[i]=accountBalances[i+1];
              accountBalances[i+1]=tempAccBalance;
          }
```

just implement this to your function that do the bubble sort

Comment: The OP wants `accountBalances` to follow the sequence of the eventually sorted `accountNumbers` too.

Comment: @Ahmed but look at his/her function prototype inside the main function, he/she even use double declaration, in the main function prototype he insisted that the `accountBalances` is not an array but a single `double` variable named accountBalances

Comment: That is a typo look at the function prototype `void dualSort(int [], double [], int);` before the `main()`.

Comment: yup but its his mistake I dunno why I got some downvote but well its SO behavior

Comment: You did not even consider touching `accountBalances`.

Comment: Although that was very guided, but I still consider it as a fix. Un-down voting.

Comment: This solution does work in the more simple manner for me, but @AhmedAkhtar 's code gives the benefit of using functions that I do need more practice with. Thank you both I'd up vote if my reputation allowed me.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a struct:

```
struct Account{
    int accountNum;
    int accountBalance;
    bool operator<(const Account& a);
};
```

Then overload the comparison operator:

```
bool Account::operator<(const Account& a);
{
    return (accountNum < a.accountNum);
}
```

Then put all your data in a struct vector using for loops:

```
std::vector<Account> accVec;
```

Finally sort vector using std::sort()

```
std::sort(accVec.begin(), accVec.end());
```

Now you have your data neatly stored in a vector in ascending order of account number.

Alternatively you can apply regular bubbleSort to sort the elements, as shown by "abcOfJavaAndCPP"

```
for(int j = 1; j < accVec.size(); ++j)
    for(int i = 1; i < accVec.size() ; ++i)
        if(accVec[i-1] < accVec[i])
            std::swap(accVec[i], accVec[i+1]);
```

Comment: The OP is not looking for an efficient sorting algorithm, he instead explicitly wants bubble sort or selection sort.

Answer (score 0):

Code can be simplified quite a bit by using some more modern C++ techniques:

```
#include <vector>

struct Account {
    double balance;
    int number;
};

bool operator<(const Account& lhs, const Account& rhs) {
    return lhs.number < rhs.number;
}

void dualSort(vector<Account>& v) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size() - 1; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != v.size() - 1; ++j) {
            if (v[j] < v[j+1]) std::swap(v[j], v[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;            // Array size
    std::vector<Account> v(ARRAY_SIZE);
    std::ifstream inputFile;

    // Open the file.
    inputFile.open("FinalNumbers.txt");

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        inputFile >> v[i].number >> v[i].balance;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    // Display the read data
    cout << "The bank account numbers are: " << endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++) {
        cout << v[count].number << "\n" << v[count].balance << " " << endl;
    }

    void dualSort(v);
}
```

Would encourage you to learn about classes, or even just structs to start, and also get familiar with `std::vector` as you should be using it a lot.